# Slanted curly brace to upshape, and \dagger, and so on

Tags: fonts

Imported from http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/anttor/

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[math]{anttor}

\begin{document}

$\{\sin x\mid 0<x<\pi\}$, $A\dagger B=C$.

\end{document}
```

[image: some description]

Comment: P.s. I want the math text is slanted anttor, and the symbols is upshape anttor.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is (there isn't even a question mark in your question!).

Comment: @Caramdir: Run the code, you will see my meaning: focus the symbol. I want an upshape one.

Comment: Please, next time write your question in the question body. Simply having "Slanted curly brace to upshape, and \dagger, and so on" in the title is not enough, because people don't know exactly want you need. Thank you.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: sorry, next time would be Okay.

Answer (score 1):

As far I see, the font that you use (antor) doesn't have the symbols that you want (\mathrm doesn't work), moreover if you look at the official example, the italics braces are a design feature.

I don't think it's a good idea, but if you will upright braces, you could try `\text\{`(with amsmath).
The right answer is perhaps to not use {anttor} if you don't want slanted braces.